# Finding a lower bound for this term

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $t$ and $n$ are positive integers. What is the best lower bound we can have for the following term?
$$1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2t} \ge ?$$
So far I am using $f(x):=x^{2t}$ is convex, and thus
$$1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2t}=f(1) - f(x) \ge \nabla f(x) (1-x)=\frac{2t}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2t-1}.$$
But the RHS goes to 0 when $t$ goes t0 0 while the LHS converges to 1.

Many thanks.

Comment: The best lower bound is the expression itself. So you have to be more specific. Best lower bound in what sense?

Comment: If you expand $(1-1/n)^{2t}$ you will find that your expression can be written as $\frac{2t}{n} - \frac{2t(2t-1)}{2n^2} + \cdots$. The more terms you include, the better the approximation will be, which can help with lower bounding with a simple expression. But as Martin R points out it is unclear what kind of lower bound you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinR I was analyzing the complexity of an algorithm and simplify it to a term like this. But this form is not common because $n$ and $t$ are still entangled. I was trying a more drastic way which simplifies $\frac{2t}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2t-1}\ge \frac{2t}{n}\frac{1}{2}^{2t-1}$, but it may not give the same conclusion as the original one. So I wonder if there is a better lower bound with same asympotical behavior as before.

Comment: @angryavian I would like to find a lower bound for this term to better analyze the complexity of an algorithm. But I am not sure if or how this can be simplied.

Comment: @fois: So you are interesting in a “good” bound for $t \to 0$? For fixed $n$?

Comment: @MartinR Well, I would like to find a lower bound term that works for $t\rightarrow \infty$ or $n\rightarrow\infty$.